# Change height of an image in material_parallax

Tags: css, r, shiny

The `shinymaterial` package includes a function called `material_parallax()` which allows for a pretty parallax effect on images while scrolling. The only parameter of the function is `image_source`. I'd like to change the height of this parallax box in my app.

Is it possible (using custom css or otherwise) to change the height of `material_parallax()` so it takes up less vertical space?

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- material_page(include_nav_bar = FALSE,
  #I'd like this parallax to be shorter
  material_parallax(
    image_source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Freudenberg_sg_Switzerland.jpg/1920px-Freudenberg_sg_Switzerland.jpg"),

  material_card(
    h1("This is just to add vertical space",
       plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$plot <- renderPlot(height = 1000,
    pairs(iris))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this css:

```
ui <- material_page(
  tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", 
                       ".parallax-container{height:150px} .parallax img{height:50%}")),
  include_nav_bar = FALSE,
  #I'd like this parallax to be shorter
  material_parallax(
    image_source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Freudenberg_sg_Switzerland.jpg/1920px-Freudenberg_sg_Switzerland.jpg"),

  material_card(
    h1("This is just to add vertical space",
       plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!